# Mudar Cor de atributo em especifico em um thema no VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pessoal estou tentando trocar as cores apenas dos itens a esquerda de um objeto em js e totalmente sem sucesso quero modificar a cor das palavras que marquei em vermelho, me ajuda plz

[image: Exemplo de objeto no JS]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ja tentei ir em setting e adicionar o seguinte comando

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Material Theme]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                  "scope": [
                    //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
                    "comment",
                    "entity.name.type.class", //class names
                    "keyword", //import, export, return…
                    "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
                    "storage.modifier", //static keyword
                    "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
                    "constant.numeric.json",
                    "constant.numeric.javascript",
                    "storage.type.class.js",
                    "storage.modifier"
                  ],
                  "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "background": "#FF0000"
                  }
                }
            ]
```

mas nao tive sucesso nenhum, help plz

Comment: https://www.lambda3.com.br/2015/10/visual-studio-code-3-customizacao/ isso pode te ajuda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code isso tbm